# Images in Keynote: how to edit rectangular mask into a parallelogram (or any other square surface)

Tags: graphics, keynote

I'd like to create a Keynote presentation that has a vintage / retro comic style. For this I want images not as boring exact rectangles (i.e. with four edges of exact 90 degrees), but in various "squary" shapes, i.e. a parallelogram, or even more "extreme" shapes that do not have any parallel sides anymore.

[image]

Is this possible in Keynote? Under **Format** → **Image** → **Mask with shape**, I only find "Rectangle", but no way to transform it (except making it smaller or bigger).